# div element not enclosing inner absolute positioned div

Tags: html, css, css-position

In my page I have an external `<div>` which contains all the page content and at the bottom of it I have the footer. The problem is if I put an absolute positioned `<div>` inside of the main one then this new `div` is not contained. Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ohy8zzqs/
If you remove the `position:absolute` from `#ss` it works perfectly. What is the solution?
I am asking for a solution because my page will load with ajax the posts and their related comments when users request them so I don't know at the beginning the total height of the page

HTML

```
<div id="AllContent2">
   <p>we</p>
   <div id="ss">   
   </div>
</div>
<div id="footer_wrapper">
  <div id="footer_inner_wrapper"> 
    <div  class="bottom">
        <p>wewqe</p>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
#AllContent2{
  position: relative;
  background: #eee;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  width: 100%;
}

#ss{
   position: absolute;
   height: 100px;
}
#footer_wrapper {
   background: #2B2B76;
   width: 100%;
   height: 40px;
}
#footer_inner_wrapper{
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0px auto;
 }
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason *why* the `#ss` element *needs* to be absolutely positioned? Perhaps there is an alternative.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do. If removing the `position:absolute` "works perfectly", why is that not an option? What purpose does `#ss` have?

Comment: The purpose of `#ss` it to put its content in particular positions of the screen. I was thinking to use `margin` instead of `position`, is that a good idea? Can I achieve the same result?